# Motion Waterfall sound

Tags: sound-effects

Trying to get some ideas on how to recreate the sound that comes out of those cheap motion led waterfalls, I have raw audio of waterfalls I have recorded, and some bird song to throw in there, but there is just a certain level of low quality :) that those do to the sound, kind of warbly or something.  Any ideas?  It is to play in the background of a couple of scenes and to be brought out at a few times to make a joke happen.

Comment: Would just using white noise help?

Answer (score 1):

Hey,

Nice little experiment! Most of these kinds of devices have very low quality soundchips in them. So my advice would be to tweak the typical quality parameters like bit reduction and samplerate and create combfilters or slowly flanging it. But keep it a steady sound, because the samples are very short in those tiny chips.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

You could try worldizing your waterfall/birdsong soundscape using some kind of low-fi recording/playback device. There are many cheap toy recorders out there which might just do the trick. You could also try re-recording the playback from a mobile phone.

Toy recorder example - www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0015Z6B34

Comment: that's even easier! you could probably do it with a casiotone or something to do sample recording and playback, play with pitch and you'll get a very low-fi quality.

Answer (score 0):

So after some goofing around and using http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXptp7ZUeIk as a rough reference.  This is what I came up with last night.

http://soundcloud.com/the-verlotta-project/sets/waterfall-phototest

The "dry" version is of the water pre speaker effecting and the wet version being post effects.

Have not added any reverb to this because that will happen later down the line.

I think the wet version accents the birdsong a bit to much.  I arrived at this by some eq, running it through noise reduction filters to introduce some artifacting, and then goofing in speakerphone.
Is there another way to introduce the noise reduction filter artifacts without actually running it through them?

I want to worldize it instead of speakerphone, but my home is really noisy as a recording enviroment unfortunantly.

Comment: great to hear what you came up with, i listened to it on my macbook, so my opinion is biased by the tiny speaker. but i think it still sounds to full bodied. it can be more resonant in my opinion. maybe use a multiband compressor/limiter and enhance a specific small bandwith to get that really cheap plastic sound?
worldizing could also create that ofcourse, but still have a try since your recording environment is a bit noisy. have fun!

Comment: @Arnoud Yeah there is something about it right now that just is not working for me, cannot pinpoint it, maybe it will work for me once I put it into the BG of the scene with verb/reflections of the room but I don't think that will really change my mind.  Going to try the multiband compression.